# Segmentation fault 11 na leitura de um arquivo CSV em C++

Tags: c++

Boa noite, pessoal! Seguinte, fiz esse código a partir de uma resposta daqui do stack overflow e ele está dando segmentation fault 11 na última linha do arquivo, alguém me ajuda a resolver, por favor!
Esse é o meu código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void read_archive(const char *in) {
ifstream file(in);
string buffer;
vector <vector<string> > linhas; //Vetor de vetor para todas as linhas
while(!file.eof()) {
    getline(file, buffer);
    stringstream ss(buffer);

    vector<string> linha;
    while(getline(ss, buffer, ';')) {
        linha.push_back(buffer);

    }
    linhas.push_back(linha);
}

    vector<unsigned long> ColunasRelevantes; //ColunasRelevantes[X];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < linhas[0].size(); i++) {
        string nomeColunas = linhas[0][i].substr(1, linhas[0][i].size() - 2); //Tirar as 2 aspas
        if(nomeColunas == "SG_PARTIDO") {
            ColunasRelevantes.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < linhas.size(); i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < ColunasRelevantes.size(); j++) {
            unsigned long Coluna = ColunasRelevantes[j];
            string texto = linhas[i][Coluna].substr(1, linhas[i][Coluna].size() - 2);
            cout << texto << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
int main () {

    read_archive("consulta_cand_2018_BR.csv");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sem ter uma noção de que conteúdo tem o arquivo é difícil de dizer o que possa não estar correto. Mas de acordo com a leitura feita no código que tem, não pode ter linhas em branco no arquivo, por isso certifique-se que a ultima linha não tem nenhuma linha em branco

Comment: O link para o csv que estou usando é esse: https://gitlab.com/oofga/eps/eps_2018_2/ep1/raw/master/data/consulta_cand_2018_BR.csv?inline=false

Comment: Tal como eu comecei por avisar, o arquivo tem uma ultima linha em branco, a linha 28.